# Recommendations on impermeable high temp material selection?

Tags: materials

I'm currently looking for a tubing that can withstand 350F+, have a shore rating of less than 80A, and must be impermeable or very close to it.

I've found a tubing called "Viton" which is close but not quite impermeable; are there any other materials offered out there that fit these specifications?

Comment: You have to define what you mean by "impermeable" in order for someone to give you a good answer. Also the wall thickness of your tubing is going to affect permeability, how thin do you want your tubing to be ?

Comment: McMaster-Carr would be a good resource for this type of search.

Comment: Impermeable meaning that water vapor or odors cannot penetrate it. I've searched McMaster.

Comment: Hi temp silicone rubber would be a good starting point. Fluorosilicone rubber would have the best chemical resistance, if you can find it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check out ePTFE tubing.

Water impermeable and bio-inert. Strong, can be really thin, and can be softer than 80A.

Regarding odor impermeable, you'll have to test.

Comment: Teflon has a hardness of 98 on the Shore A scale, not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: That's PTFE.  Look up ePTFE, e is for expanded and is much softer.

Comment: Really, you are suggesting foamed Teflon, what will happen to your permeability?

Comment: PTFE is permeable to Cl ( and likely others) at moderate temp. like 150 F. I have seen many magnetic stirrers ( magnet encased in 1 to 2 mm thick PTFE) swell and even burst while stirring water solutions for corrosion testing) .Cl ,etc . permeates and corrodes the magnet material.

Answer (score 1):

Viton is about as close to "impermeable" as it gets. Viton gaskets are what are commonly used for ultra-high vacuum chamber systems which can achieve vacuum levels on the order of 10E-12 Torr.